# RichApi.Error ItemNotFound Office.context.document.addHandlerAsync

Tags: office365, office-js, office-addins

I am using Office.context.document.addHandlerAsync on Context click event trigger. When the click is triggered, i get error:

Promise rejection: ItemNotFound ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: RichApi.Error: ItemNotFound
when clicked on Office.context.document.addHandlerAsync used

When using hosted version of office:

after deployment. 

This is happening when using hosted version of office.

Comment: Where is your manifest? Where and how do you add event handlers? Did you try to run any samples from the github repo? Do they work correctly? What is your host?

Comment: It is working. but this error keeps popping up once I click outside content control. has to deal with this.